Using Overleaf, how can I put `\section{}` commands in the preamble so I can access them in the sidebar menu?
Overleaf is a very popular site for writing and compiling LaTeX documents. For many people, including myself, finding solutions to problems that are catered to Overleaf users is sometimes difficult. There's no doubt that the increased freedom of writing and compiling LaTeX natively provides as much editorial liberty as you could ask for when drafting complex documents, however, many of us have gladly sacrificed a bit of that freedom for the streamlined and comfortable experience of Overleaf.
For several hours I was trying to find a solution to a very minor problem I had when drafting documents in Overleaf. How can I put sections in my preamble without causing any errors? This might seem like a pointless endeavor as sections are namely meant to be literal section headings rendered in the document. However, Overleaf interprets the section commands, e.g. \section{}, \subsection{}, etc., and allows for a clickable hyperlink in its sidebar menu. This makes it very convenient to hop around to different places in the document without having to excessively scroll about.

In many cases, your preamble itself might be very, very long and the convenience brought by adding sections to the main document might be desired in the preamble itself. In fact, all you need to do is add \section{} lines to the preamble and they'll show up in that sidebar menu. However, the issue that arises is the compiler spits out an error at these section lines and tells you they must be preceded by \begin{document}. If you're not using "Stop on First Error" mode when compiling or you're not someone who is bothered by the little red number that indicates how many errors are in your .tex file, then problem solved. However, if either of those two describes you then you'd be asking the same question I have:
How can I have preamble sections show up in the sidebar without raising errors when I compile?

tl;dr at end of post
The solution is in fact remarkably simple. So much so that this likely isn't even a problem at all for veteran LaTeX users. However, for those of us who often times struggle with even remembering basic commands it is not obvious how to rectify this dilemma. I found a convenient and easy (only requires a few lines) solution that I arrived at after simplifying one of the answers to the TeX Stack Exchange question: Ignore commands when compiling. The solution is to merely define a "self defined conditional" via \newif (a quick and easy explanation plus tutorial can be found here: LaTeX/Plain TeX: Self defined conditionals – WikiBooks) in the preamble before you start sectioning. This solution can be seen in the following MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifOverleafIgnore % ---> Establish a new Boolean variable

\OverleafIgnorefalse % ---> Set the Boolean as false

\makeatother

\ifOverleafIgnore   %      | The compiler will not read this line but
\section*{Preamble} % <--- | Overleaf still identifies the section command
\fi                 %      | and makes a sidebar clickable link to it

\ifOverleafIgnore
\subsection*{Packages}
\fi
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                                                   %
%                                                   %
%                     PACKAGES                      %
%                                                   %
%                                                   %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ifOverleafIgnore
\subsection*{Commands}
\fi
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                                                   %
%                                                   %
%                     COMMANDS                      %
%                                                   %
%                                                   %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ifOverleafIgnore
\subsection*{Settings}
\fi
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                                                   %
%                                                   %
%                     SETTINGS                      %
%                                                   %
%                                                   %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{Minimal Working Example}
\author{David G}
\date{Last Updated: \today}

\begin{document}
\ifOverleafIgnore
\section*{Title}
\fi
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-1]
\section{Body}
\lipsum[2-5]
\section{Conclusion}
\lipsum[5-6]
\ifOverleafIgnore
\section*{End of Document}
\fi
\end{document}





Overleaf View












You can see that not only does this allow for these "invisible sections" to be placed in the preamble, but more so they can go anywhere in your document. As seen, I have placed one at the very beginning labeled "Title" and one at the very end of the document labeled "End of Document."
I hope this helps someone as it took me a while to figure out how to do something that, all things considered, is very simple in execution. I hope this hasn't been answered already somewhere else, I certainly could not find it written about anywhere on Stack Exchange.
tl;dr
In your preamble before you need any "invisible sections" write
\makeatletter
\newif\ifOverleafIgnore % ---> Establish a new Boolean variable
\OverleafIgnorefalse % ---> Set the Boolean as false
\makeatother

If you want an "invisible section" anywhere—preamble or document environment—you need to place the section command inside a conditional like so:
\ifOverleafIgnore
\section*{Invisible Section only seen in sidebar}
\fi

As per cfr's comment an even easier way to go about this is to avoid needing to define a Bool, which I called \OverleafIgnore and just place the section command inside a predefined false Bool like this:
\iffalse
\section*{Invisible Section only seen in sidebar}
\fi


you could just use \iffalse\section{marker}\fi and not define anything ....
